# elm327 and OBD II PID specification

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

i plugged elm327 mini(bluetooth) to my car(peugeot 3008)

when i have tested some commands, i found not ordinary response.

```
ATZ
ELM327 v2.1
ATSP0
OK
ATDP0
ISO 15765-4 (CAN 11/500)
ATE0
OK
ATL0
OK
0100
SEARCHING...\r4100983BA011\r1: 06410080000010\r\r>
```

by [OBD-II PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs), i thought "0100" means "PIDs support[01-20]" and return 4 data bytes. but i received more than 4 bytes (multi-line like CAN style was displayed)

does OBD-II specification is wrong? or i am missing something?

p.s "0101" also returns more than 4 data bytes (using multiline)

```
410100040000\r1: 0641010006E000\r2: 0041010006E000\r3: 0041010006E000\r4: 03618D6106E000\r\r>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting responses from multiple ECUs
If you want to get their addresses then do

```
ath1
0100
```

ath1 turn on header, 0100 queries for a resonse
you will get the response like:

```
7E8064100983BA011
7E906410080000010
```

the first one (7E8) is from the engine, the 2nd (7E9) is from the transmission.
If you just want to hear from the engine alone run

```
atsh7e0
```

for transmission, if available do

```
atsh7e1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your vehicle or OBD simulator has returned responses from two possible ECUs. The "**4100983BA011**" is from the first and "**410080000010**" from the second.

Send the command again, but use **ATH1** before sending 0100 and you will see the CAN ID of the source addresses of the ECUs sending their responses to your diagnostics tool.